# Override urlFormEncoded parser for charset - Play Framework 2.3.x

Tags: scala, encoding, playframework

how could I override `urlFormEncoded` parser to use another charset in Play 2.3.x (Scala)?

I'm writing BBS software which works in Japanese environment with Play framework 2.3.x in Scala.

The problem is about charset: Client POSTs request with url encoded (aka. "percent encoded") form parameters encoded in `Shift-JIS` -- famous charset in Japan -- but Play decodes it as `UTF-8`. That is predictable because it is hardcoded in https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/ContentTypes.scala#L515 .

I cannot modify BBS clients' encoding because it is de-facto standard.

Thus, I must rewrite or override url encoding decoder in Play to use `Shift_JIS`.

There may be some solutions:

1. Manually build Play from modified source code and use it.
2. Intercept request and decode body as `Shift_JIS`, then re-encode body as `UTF-8`.
3. Create custom parser which extends `play.api.mvc.BodyParsers.parse` and use it.

Most hopeful choice I thought is 3, but I cannot create `object` which extends `play.api.mvc.BodyParsers.parse`.

So, how could I override default parser and use it (or there are other better solutions)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The default parser uses `charset` of RequestHeader if available. `charset` is determined by `Content-Type` header. So I assume that the client doesn't set `Content-Type` header.

One way is changing the `charset` by wrapping RequestHeader.

Define a wrapper.

```
class WrappedRequestHeader(rh: RequestHeader) extends RequestHeader {
  override def id = rh.id
  override def secure = rh.secure
  override def uri = rh.uri
  override def remoteAddress = rh.remoteAddress
  override def queryString = rh.queryString
  override def method = rh.method
  override def headers = rh.headers
  override def path = rh.path
  override def version = rh.version
  override def tags = rh.tags
}
```

Define a request header which returns a constant `charset` if an original header doesn't have it.

```
class DefaultCharsetRequestHeader(rh: RequestHeader, defaultCharset: String) extends WrappedRequestHeader(rh) {
  override lazy val charset = rh.charset orElse Some(defaultCharset) // Or always use Some(defaultCharset) if you want
}
```

Then you can create a BodyParser from any default parser.

```
  def createParser[A](parser: BodyParser[A], defaultCharset: String): BodyParser[A] = BodyParser[A] { rh =>
    parser(new DefaultCharsetRequestHeader(rh, defaultCharset))
  }
```

Or you can create a Filter if you want to apply it widely.

```
class DefaultCharsetFilter(defaultCharset: String) extends Filter {
  override def apply(f: (RequestHeader) => Future[Result])(rh: RequestHeader): Future[Result] =
    f(new DefaultCharsetRequestHeader(rh, defaultCharset))
}
```

I haven't tried above code yet, but I hope it works.

Comment: It seems to be good but doesn't run;
`[error]  method charset needs to be a stable, immutable value
[error]   override def charset = rh.charset orElse Some(defaultCharset) // Or always use Some(defaultCharset) if you want`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem renewing request using apache httpcomponents.

We can retrieve URL-encoded data as raw text, specifying `parse.torelantText` as body parser. Then manually parse URL-encoded data into `Map[String, Seq[String]]` and recreate `Request`.

I show the code below.

Define dependency in `build.sbt`:

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.4"`

Define object to convert `Request[String]` into `Request[Map[String, Seq[String]]]`:

```
import play.api.mvc.{ Headers, Request }

object PercentEncoding {
  import java.net.URI
  import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
  import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils
  import org.apache.http.NameValuePair
  def extractSJISRequest(request: Request[String]) = {
    val body = request.body
    val parsed: Seq[NameValuePair] = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI("http://example.com/?" + body), "Shift_JIS")
    val newBody = parsed.map { pair ⇒ (pair.getName, Seq(pair.getValue)) }.toMap
    new Request[Map[String, Seq[String]]] {
      override def body: Map[String, Seq[String]] = newBody

      override def uri: String = request.uri

      override def remoteAddress: String = request.remoteAddress

      override def queryString: Map[String, Seq[String]] = request.queryString

      override def method: String = request.method

      override def headers: Headers = request.headers

      override def path: String = request.path

      override def version: String = request.version

      override def tags: Map[String, String] = request.tags

      override def id: Long = request.id
    }
  }
}
```

Then convert original `request` using `PercentEncoding` and define implicit request value instead of original `request`:

```
def hogehoge = Action(parse.tolerantText) { request ⇒
    implicit val newRequest = PercentEncoding.extractSJISRequest(request)
...
}
```

And it works.